# How to use Gmail API to create a client_secret.json that only allows sending emails?

Tags: python, gmail-api

Is it possible to use the gmail API to create a client_secret.json file that will only enable sending of emails from an address? I don't see anything in the gmail API documentation on this subject. Correct me if I am wrong, but with the secret json file generated [in this tutorial](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/python), the user would be able to read messages in the inbox also, correct?

That is, I want to have an OAuth app that allows users with the client_secret.json to send emails, but not to read any of the emails in the inbox, outbox, etc.

Comment: If you use the scope `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.send`, like mentioned [**here**](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/auth/scopes), you will only be able to send emails.

Comment: Thanks @Tholle. I suppose that's not exactly what I'm looking for. I have a shared email address that will be used by multiple parties to send automated emails via a script. Each user writes their own script. Therefore, if I rely only on the API scope, I'm reliant on users not changing the scope. That is, a curious and/or malicious user could simply change the scope and read the inbox and/or outbox. I'd like to generate a 'client_secret.json' that will cause a change in scope from 'send' to anything else to fail.

Comment: @Tholle - You get what I'm saying, right? A user could go into the script and just change 'gmail.send' to something else, including just 'https://mail.google.com/', which would give them full access to the email account.